# org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I want to add an order by restriction to a criteria in Hibernate.
I have two tables Event and MainEvent with the relation One To Many (a MainEvent has many Events).

```
    final Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
            Event.class);
    criteria.createAlias("mainEvent.date", "deadline");
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("deadline"));
    return criteria.list();
```

When I try to run this it gives me the following error:

org.hibernate.QueryException: not an association: date.

MainEvent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN_EVENT")
public class MainEventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "MAIN_EVENT_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "MAIN_EVENT_DATE")
    private Date date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainEvent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EventEntity> events = new ArrayList<EventEntity>();

}
```

Event entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENT")
public class EventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "EVENT_ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_EVENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private MainEventEntity mainEvent;

}
```

Comment: post your entity code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the API for [Criteria.createAlias](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), you can create alias **only** for associations not for the fields of an association.

```
createAlias

Criteria createAlias(String associationPath,
                     String alias)
                     throws HibernateException
Join an association, assigning an alias to the joined association.



Parameters:
associationPath - A dot-seperated property path
alias - The alias to assign to the joined association (for later reference).
Returns:
this (for method chaining)
```

Comment: Would have been lovely to see what we should have done in context, rather than a quick paste from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
   final Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
        Event.class);
criteria.createAlias("mainEvent", "me");
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("me.deadline"));
return criteria.list();
```